# Deep AR Flutter: Direct local .aar file dependencies are not supported when building an AAR

Tags: flutter, augmented-reality

I'm following the documentation as given in the plugin page on [camera_deep_ar](https://pub.dev/packages/camera_deep_ar)

1. I have set the minimumSdkVersion to 19
2. Given the permissions correctly in the AndroidManifest.xml
3. Set up the proguard-android.txt file correctly
4. And used the sample code given in the docs

This is the error it gives me on running the app.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':camera_deep_ar:bundleDebugAar'.
> Direct local .aar file dependencies are not supported when building an AAR. The resulting AAR would be broken because the classes and Android resources from any local .aar file dependencies would not be packaged in the resulting AAR. Previous versions of the Android Gradle Plugin produce broken AARs in this case too (despite not throwing this error).
```

Comment: did you solve this error? i'm facing a similar problem with another plugin.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xs6lHOUrP0o&t=1871s&ab_channel=LetCodewithKoushik
I followed these steps and it worked out finally.

Comment: android/app/build.gradle:

buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro' 
}
}
Use these versions in android/build.gradle: 
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
}

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be thrown from the camera_deep_ar plugin. Try rebuilding the Flutter project to check if this can solve the references in the project. To do this, run `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get`.